# General formula for the product $(x+1)\prod\limits_{m=1}^n (x^{2m}+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

Please Forgive me for any mistake in the proposal of the problem

***Problem***

> How we can we find the general expansion of $$(x+1)\prod_{m=1}^n (x^{2m}+1),$$ where $n$ is any positive integer.

***An example***

> For example if $n=1$ ,then the required product is $(x+1)(x^2+1)$.
>   If $n=2$, then the required product is $(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$.
>    And so on the series is going like this.

***My approach***

> I put $x^2=a$ and I decided to first solve the value after $x+1$.

***Two methods***

**First way**

> So I got a new  product which was $(a+1)(a^2+1)(a^3+1)(a^4+1)....(a^n+1)$. I tried putting the value of $n$ as $1,2,3,4$ but I could not find any pattern.

**Second way**

> I multiplied the first term  and the last term to get $(a+1)(a^n+1)=a^{n+1} +a^n+a+1$. Then I multiplied the second last term with the second term to get$(a^2+1)(a^{n-1}+1)=a^{n+1} +a^{n-1} +a^2 +1$. 
>    Then I put $a^{n+1}+1$ as $y$  and I got the general form of a term to get a new product. I again tried it for $1,2,3,4$ but I could not find any pattern.

**Third way**

> This time I am not excluding $x+1$ and I am not taking $x^2=a$. I tried solving it as by taking $x+1=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ and $x^2+1=\frac{x^4-1}{x^2-1}$ . So $x^{2n}+1=\frac{x^{4n}-1}{x^{2n}-1}$ So when we multiply them then some terms get cancelled. Example : When we solve it till $x^8+1$ , we get $\frac{(x^{12}-1)(x^{16}-1)}{(x-1)(x^6-1)}$ . I know that $x^{12}-1$ and $x^{16}-1$ can get cancelled if we try to solve it further but how will we cancel $x^6-1$?

Please help me. Please  do not use derivatives or integrals as I am not  through with them .
Forgive me for any mistake in the wording of the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it $ (x+1)\prod_{m=1}^n x^{2m}$ or $(x+1)\prod_{m=1}^n (x^{2m} +1)$ ?

Comment: The initial formula does not match the examples.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the initial factor, it looks (from the examples you give) as that we are speaking about
$$
P(x,n) = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + x^{\,2\,k} } \right)} 
$$

Now,
$$
\eqalign{
  & \prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + x^{\,2\,k} } \right)}  = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + \left( {x^{\,2} } \right)^{\,k} } \right)}  = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + y^{\,k} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {1 + y} \right)\left( {1 + y^{\,2} } \right) \cdots \left( {1 + y^{\,n} } \right) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \;m\, \le \,n\left( {n + 1} \right)/2} {f(m,n)y^{\;m} }  \cr} 
$$
so that $f(m,n)$ represents the
  *Number of partitions of $m$ into distinct parts ranging from $1$ to $n$*
and unfortunately there is no closed form for the number of partitions of a given number (into distinct or repeated parts).

But, of course, you can manipulate the product in various ways depending on what you are aiming to.

One way is to take the logarithm of 
$$
P(y,n) = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + y^{\,k} } \right)} 
$$
and reach to
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \ln P(y,n) = \ln \left( {\prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + y^{\,k} } \right)} } \right)
  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\ln \left( {1 + y^{\,k} } \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\ln \left( {1 + y^{\,k} } \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j + 1} \frac{{y^{\,k\,j} }}{j}} }  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,m} {\left( {\sum\limits_{\left\{ 
  {\begin{array}{*{20}c} {k\backslash m}  \\   {1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n}  \\\end{array}} \right.} 
{\;\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m/k + 1} k} } \right)\frac{{y^{\,m} }}{m}}  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Eventually, to take the derivative
$$
\frac{d}{{dy}}\ln P(y,n) = \frac{{P'(y,n)}}{{P(y,n)}} = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,m} {\left( {\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {k\backslash m}  \\
   {1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n}  \\
\end{array}} \right.} {\;\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m/k + 1} k} } \right)y^{\,m - 1} } 
$$
which will also equal
$$
{{P'(y,n)} \over {P(y,n)}} = {{\sum\limits_{1\, \le \;j\, \le \,n} {j\,y^{\,j - 1} \prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k \ne j\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + y^{\,k} } \right)} } } \over {\prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + y^{\,k} } \right)} }} = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;j\, \le \,n} {{{j\,y^{\,j - 1} } \over {1 + y^{\,j} }}} 
$$

Another approach is trough the $k$-th roots of $-1$
$$
P(y,n) = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + y^{\,k} } \right)}  = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \;k\, \le \,n} {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \;j\, \le \,k - 1} {\left( {y - e^{\,i\,{{\left( {2j + 1} \right)} \over k}\pi } } \right)} } 
$$
etc.

Comment: Can we solve it without using partitions?

Comment: Or is there any specific way to start with the problem to make it easier?(not necessarily that the formula can be derived using that approach)

Comment: what do you mean by "solve" ?  any "nice" recast of the product will always involve partitions of <-> divisors of and equivalents . I added an example of the many ways in which the product can be "manipulated", and the approach to take depends on where to go (recursion ? asymptotics? ..?)